# LogRecord attributes in a derived logger

Tags: python, logging, formatting, derived-class

I want to use a logger which also knows to handle my additional log levels *verbose* and *trace*. Therefore I created a custom logger deriving from a base logger

```
import logging

class DefaultLogger(logging.Logger):

    def __init__(self, name):
        logging.Logger.__init__(self, name)

        # Using propagation of child to parent, by default
        self.propagate = True
        self.setLevel(logging.NOTSET)

    def verbose(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):
        self.log(logging.VERBOSE, msg, *args, **kwargs)

    def trace(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):
        self.log(logging.TRACE, msg, *args, **kwargs)
```

I use the logger with some standard format [LogRecords attributes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes) like `filename` or `funcName`.

```
    "format":"%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(filename)s:%(funcName)s - %(message)s"
```

For the origin log levels this works as a charm,

> 2021-10-28 09:47:32,039 - INFO - uploadData.py:main - Message

but for my custom log levels I get the origin of my custom logger class:

> 2021-10-28 09:47:32,040 - TRACE - DefaultLogger.py:trace - Message

Of course this is not what I want to have, I am not interested in this class, I want to have the calling method.

What do I have to do to fix this problem?

Comment: No answer so far? Is my question too complicated? Is my use case so unusual?

Answer (score 0):

I have searched a lot about this problem. The main problem is obviously, that in the base class `Logger`, there is the `findCaller` method, which searches in the Stack for the calling module.
In my case thats my derived class and that's one level to low.

My choice would have been to overwrite the `findCaller`, but I found a simpler solution. Maybe a bit ugly, but working like a charme:

I replaced the line ..

```
self.log(logging.VERBOSE, msg, *args, **kwargs)
```

by ..

```
self._log(logging.VERBOSE, msg, args, exc_info=None, extra=None, stack_info=False)
```

As `log` internally calls `_log` and I omit this one method, the findCaller method now have the right resolution as it have exactly the same count of calling methods like in the standard Logger.